# Metro UI live tiles - https://metroui.org.ua

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, microsoft-metro

I want to know whether it's possible to change the time duration between the transitions of each live tile, as at the moment they are changing too quick for my liking. You can find more information at the bottom of [this](https://metroui.org.ua/tiles.html) page.

Thanks in advance.

[SOLVED] Line 7508 of metro.js contains the duration setting.

Comment: I know that's already solved, but it's good to see someone that agree Metro!

Comment: A metro UI always has it's uses. I find it very useful to create dashboards using live tiles to display data.

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] Line 7508 of metro.js contains the duration setting.